# Photoshop: copying multiple layers across documents without drag and drop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, automation, actions

I have been trying to create a new action to speed up a process i do which involves copying and pasting layers but Photoshop actions do not record drag and drop and i have been unsuccessful in finding a way.

Is there a way copy and paste many layers in to a different document which is able to be recorded in an action? or is it possible for the drag and drop to be recorded into an action?

Comment: Sorry but this isn't a duplicate question, i already know of the duplicate layer function and have tried it, maybe i should have made my question clearer. With the duplicate layer you to select an open file or create new and within an action this just doesn't work because of the many different templates i use but i need to be able to quickly move layers from one file onto an already made template so the name names constantly change.

Comment: So is there a way to duplicate to previous file or as in my original question is there a way copy and paste many layers in to a different document which is able to be recorded in an action? or is it possible for the drag and drop to be recorded into an action?

Answer (score 4):

Highlight the layer in the Layers Panel and from the panel menu choose `Duplicate Layers...`

[image]

You're then presented with a dialog window where you can select *where* to duplicate to. All any currently open documents with be listed in the drop down as well as the "new" option at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but this did not answer my question.

Comment: @Kinzett not sure why not ... .. it's recordable in an action.